# How to delete from a table in Redshift using PySpark?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to write a `PySpark` script to insert some data into a table in Redshift using Databricks's `spark-redshift` library, and delete some older data in place of it. Is there a way to directly delete data from Redshift using Spark? Like maybe executing a Spark SQL statement that updates the Redshift table directly?
I know Redshift uses Postgres and Spark uses Hive, but I need to run this query everyday and with the new AWS Glue coming, which supports `PySpark`, I was wondering if there's a way to do it in `PySpark`.